# Python Global variable gives NameError

Tags: python

My code:

```
def draw_lines(img, lines, color, thickness) :
    x_right = []
    y_right = []
    x_left = []
    y_left = []
    numItr = 1

    for line in lines :
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines :
        global numItr
        numItr += 1
```

And this is error:

```
NameError: name 'numItr' is not defined
```

Comment: instead of posting image, please post your code here

Comment: Please copy paste your code, also this says the variable was not defined before you use it

Comment: what are parameter values you are passing to the function. can you post exact details?Let us know what are you trying to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `global` or `nonlocal` here, just:

```
def draw_lines(img, lines, color, thickness) :
    x_right = []
    y_right = []
    x_left = []
    y_left = []
    numItr = 1

    for line in lines :
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines :
            numItr += 1
```

You only need `global` if you want to write to a module level variable.
And you only need `nonlocal` if you want to write to a variable that's local to a lexically enclosing function, e.g. the function in which you define your function.

Both cases don't apply to your code, you're just staying inside one function.

In your case the interpreter complains, while by using the word `global` you indicate that there is a module level variable called `numItr`, which there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is that `numItr` not declared before `draw_lines` function. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/6876911